# download file php program show error

Tags: php, mysql

```
   // this php program showing no id was passed error, why its showing this error,
this program used for upload files into mysql database and list the files then create links for the uploaded file to download. but i had some problem, the download links shows error why?
```

kindly help me to solve this problem...

## listfile.php

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Paging</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'sathishcst';
    $dbpass = 'geni7joy';
    $rec_limit = 10;
    
    $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
    if(! $conn )
    {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('gat-india.com');
    /* Get total number of records */
    $sql = "select*from enquiry_info,resume_file ";
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_NUM );
    $rec_count = $row[0];
    
    if( isset($_GET{'page'} ) )
    {
       $page = $_GET{'page'} + 1;
       $offset = $rec_limit * $page ;
    }
    else
    {
       $page = 0;
       $offset = 0;
    }
    $left_rec = $rec_count - ($page * $rec_limit);
    $sql = "select * from enquiry_info,resume_file where enquiry_info.id=resume_file.id\n"
        . "ORDER BY `resume_file`.`id` DESC limit $offset, $rec_limit";
    /*$sql = "SELECT id,name,email,phone ".
           "FROM pays ".
           "LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
    */
    $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
    if(! $retval )
    {
      die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
    }
      echo '<table width="100%" border="1px" cellpadding="5px">
                    <tr>
                        <td><b>EmpName</b></td>
                        <td><b>Email</b></td>
                        <td><b>Mobile</b></td>
                        <td><b>Name</b></td>
                     <!--   <td><b>Mime</b></td>
                        <td><b>Size (bytes)</b></td>-->
                        <td><b>Created</b></td>
                        <td><b>Download resume</b></td>
                    </tr>';
     
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval, MYSQL_ASSOC))
    {
        echo "
                    <tr>
                        <td>{$row['enqname']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['email']}</td>
                        <td>+91-{$row['phone']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['name']}</td>
                      <!--  <td>{$row['mime']}</td>
                        <td>{$row['size']}</td>-->
                        <td>{$row['created']}</td>
                        <td><a href='getfiles.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td>
                    </tr>";
    } 
     echo '</table>';
    if( $page > 0 )
    {
       $last = $page - 2;
       echo "<hr><center><a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a> |";
       echo "<a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a></center><hr>";
    }
    else if( $page == 0 )
    {
       echo "<hr><br><center><a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$page\">Next 10 Records</a>";
    }
    else if( $left_rec < $rec_limit )
    {
       $last = $page - 2;
       echo "<hr><br><center><a href=\"$_PHP_SELF?page=$last\">Last 10 Records</a></center>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
    ?>
    
    
//    here the above list files working correctly... below only showing error.
```

## getfile.php

```
    <?php
    // Make sure an ID was passed
    if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    // Get the ID
        $id = intval($_GET['id']);
     
        // Make sure the ID is in fact a valid ID
        if($id <= 0) {
            die('The ID is invalid!');
        }
        else {
            // Connect to the database
            $dbLink = new mysqli('localhost', 'sathishcst', 'geni7joy', 'gat-india.com');
            if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                die("MySQL connection failed: ". mysqli_connect_error());
            }
     
            // Fetch the file information
            $query = "
                SELECT `mime`, `name`, `size`, `data`
                FROM `resume_file`
                WHERE `id` = {$id}";
            $result = $dbLink->query($query);
     
            if($result) {
                // Make sure the result is valid
                if($result->num_rows == 1) {
                // Get the row
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
     
                    // Print headers
                    header("Content-Type: ". $row['mime']);
                    header("Content-Length: ". $row['size']);
                    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=". $row['name']);
     
                    // Print data
                    echo $row['data'];
                }
                else {
                    echo 'Error! No image exists with that ID.';
                }
     
                / Free the mysqli resources
                @mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
            else {
                echo "Error! Query failed: <pre>{$dbLink->error}</pre>";
            }
            @mysqli_close($dbLink);
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Error! No ID was passed.';
    }
    ?>
```

The php program is showing the `no id was passed`-error, why its showing this error ?

This program used for upload files into mysql database and list the files then create links for the uploaded file to download. but i had some problem, the download links shows error why?

Comment: What error is occurring?

Comment: Because there `isset($_GET['id'])` is false?

Comment: the error was showing "no id was passed or id invalid", can you please help how resolve this error?

Comment: Have you checked if the URL is properly constructed? I mean does the url contain the required ID?

Comment: Yes its have ID field

Comment: i use following url property .<td><a href='getfiles.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td>

Answer (score 0):

You should check the file name of getfile.php  link  in  listfile.php

`<td><a href='getfiles.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td>`

and chage it to

`<td><a href='getfile.php?id={$row['id']}'>{$row['name']}</a></td>`.

The href file is not matching with provided.

Comment: yes, bro, i was made this change also, but that doesn't work.